# Vue.js loading data

Tags: javascript, combobox, vue.js

I've got a couple of comboboxes in my Vue.js application. 
I load the combobox data in the ready method. Like this:

```
   ready () {
    this.getTypes();
    this.getLocations();
  },
```

So my problem:

When I go to another page and add a couple of more options for in the combobox and then go back to the page where the combobox is it's not added yet.. But if I refresh the page it's there!

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: How is the combobox set up? How does your app "go to another page"? What do the `getTypes` and `getLocations` functions do to your model? What does the other page do to add options?

Comment: you need to add a watch!

Comment: Please write all the codings that you are using

Comment: Are you using `keep-alive`? https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#keep-alive